# linear algebra: convert matrix to another matrix

Tags: r, math, matrix, linear-algebra

How to convert the following matrix

```
matrix(c(5,3,1,0,3,1,0,0,1),ncol=3,byrow = T)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    3    1
[2,]    0    3    1
[3,]    0    0    1
```

into

```
matrix(c(5,-4,3,-2,0,1),ncol=2,byrow = T)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5   -4
[2,]    3   -2
[3,]    0    1
```

Background:

I am trying to get the approximation (while being conservative) of the following system of equations:

```
5x+3y+z

3y+z

z
```

while given

```
x+y+z = a value

z= a value
```

The best I can think of is:

```
5x+3y+z \approx 5x+5y+z = 5*(x+y+z)-4*(z)

3y+z \approx 3x+3y+z = 3*(x+y+z)-2*(z)

z = 1*(z)
```

which is the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that you actually have a new mapping like `x' --> x+y+z` and `z' --> z`, so you'd better establish a transfer matrix `u` like

```
> u
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    0    0    1
```

such that `[x'; z'] = u %*% [x; y; z]`.

Then you can use `MASS::ginv(u)` to complete the chain of transforming

```
> mat %*% MASS::ginv(u)
              [,1] [,2]
[1,]  4.000000e+00 -3.0
[2,]  1.500000e+00 -0.5
[3,] -2.220446e-16  1.0
```

since `mat %*% [x;y;z] --> mat %*% ginv(u) %*% [x'; y']`

## Data

```
mat <- matrix(c(5, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1), ncol = 3, byrow = T)

u <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), 2, byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: This is awesome! Do you think there is any chance to get the expected output? Feel free to add additional assumptions if needed.

Comment: I think I need to somehow convert ```mat``` to ```mat2 <- matrix(c(5, 5, 1, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1), ncol = 3, byrow = T)``` and then apply ```mat2 %*% MASS::ginv(u)```. But the tricky part is to get ```mat2```. Thank you!